# MATLAB: different alphas for different patch objects

Tags: matlab, patch, alpha-transparency

Ok, so the `patch` function lets us draw multiple polygons with e.g.

```
patch(X,Y,'r')
```

where `X` and `Y` are m-by-n matrices. This draws n polygons with m vertices.

But what if I want each of those n polygons to have a unique alpha transparency value?

```
patch(X,Y,'r', ??? SOME CODE TO USE A VECTOR OF ALPHA VALUES ???)
```

The documentation is confusing me to death. I can't use a `for` loop, since I need to draw many patch objects very quickly. Could somebody kindly provide a code example? Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the `FaceVertexAlphaData` property is the key:  Here is some sample code:

```
X = [...
    1  2  3 ; ...
    4  5  6 ; ...
    7  8  9 ; ...
    10 11 12];
Y = [...
    2  5  8; ...
    3  6  9; ...
    1  4  7; ...
    -1 3  6];
h = patch( X, Y, 'r');
set(h,'FaceAlpha','flat','FaceVertexAlphaData',[.2; .4; .8])
```

`docsearch patch properties` for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was confused when I saw that even with alphas 0.2 and 0.8 the first polygon appears fully transparent and the third fully opaque. I searched and found that Matlab has alpha limits and it automatically fits them to the alpha data of the objects. Calling `alim([0 1])` fixes it! Hooray :)

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't paying enough to the actual colors of the patches to notice that important subtlety.